# Netbeans 10.0 IDE with C++ plugin could not install some modules: com.jcraft.jsch

Tags: c++, netbeans, plugins

Having installed Netbeans 10.0, I wanted to install the C/C++ Plugin. However during the installation of the plugin, I get the following warning messages:

```
Warning - could not install some modules: com.jcraft.jsch - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /home/vaddina/.netbeans/10.0/modules/com-jcraft-jsch.jar: Cannot start com.jcraft.jsch state remains INSTALLED after start()
```

I have to option to disable these modules and continue but after doing that I cannot set any C++ build hosts (Causes the following exception). I have a feeling the two issues are related. How can I get this working ? Any help is very appreaciated.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
Caused: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException starting from ModuleCL@5cf2e19c[org.netbeans.modules.dlight.nativeexecution] with possible defining loaders null and declared parents [ModuleCL@2c9eaf6f[org.netbeans.modules.extexecution], ModuleCL@6273bb7b[org.netbeans.modules.terminal], org.netbeans.JarClassLoader@67dd5a36, Netigso[reference:file:/home/vaddina/.netbeans/10.0/modules/com-jcraft-jsch.jar], ModuleCL@1f237821[org.netbeans.api.io], ModuleCL@7cee86e7[org.openide.io], ModuleCL@1efed738[org.netbeans.api.progress], ModuleCL@56313df4[org.netbeans.libs.jna], ModuleCL@4bf24d31[org.netbeans.modules.keyring], ModuleCL@7a12f991[org.netbeans.api.annotations.common], ...1 more]
    at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
Caused: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jcraft/jsch/JSchException
    at org.netbeans.modules.nativeexecution.support.HostPropertiesPanelProviderImpl.getHostPropertyPanel(HostPropertiesPanelProviderImpl.java:39)
    at org.netbeans.modules.nativeexecution.support.HostConfigurationPanel.<init>(HostConfigurationPanel.java:79)
    at org.netbeans.modules.nativeexecution.api.ui.util.NativeExecutionUIUtils.getConfigurationPanel(NativeExecutionUIUtils.java:32)
    at org.netbeans.modules.cnd.remote.ui.wizard.CreateHostVisualPanel2.<init>(CreateHostVisualPanel2.java:92)
    at org.netbeans.modules.cnd.remote.ui.wizard.CreateHostWizardPanel2.getComponent(CreateHostWizardPanel2.java:83)
    at org.netbeans.modules.cnd.remote.ui.wizard.CreateHostWizardPanel2.getComponent(CreateHostWizardPanel2.java:57)
    at org.netbeans.modules.cnd.remote.ui.setup.CreateHostWizardIterator.getPanels(CreateHostWizardIterator.java:123)
    at org.netbeans.modules.cnd.remote.ui.setup.CreateHostWizardIterator.current(CreateHostWizardIterator.java:146)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.updateStateOpen(Unknown Source)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.updateState(Unknown Source)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor._updateState(Unknown Source)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at org.openide.NotifyDescriptor.getterCalled(Unknown Source)
    at org.openide.DialogDescriptor.isModal(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.services.NbDialog.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.services.DialogDisplayerImpl$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.services.DialogDisplayerImpl$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.NbMutexEventProvider$Event$1AWTWorker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:303)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
    at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
[catch] at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Comment: I encountered this same issue. Did you maybe already find a solution in the mean time?

Comment: No .. not really ! I ended up using QtCreator instead !